# replace only matches the beginning of the string

Tags: sql-server, replace, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012, diacritics

I'm trying to write a function to replace the Romanian diacritic letters (`ĂÂÎȘȚ`) to their Latin letter equivalents (`AAIST`, respectively).

SQL Server's `replace` function deals with `Ă`, `Â`, and `Î` just fine.

It seems to have a weird problem with `Ș` and `Ț`, though: they are only replaced if they are found at the beginning of the string.

For [example](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/41752):

```
select replace(N'Ș', N'Ș', N'-')
-- '-'   # OK

select replace(N'ȘA', N'Ș', N'-')
-- '-A'  # OK

select replace(N'AȘ', N'Ș', N'-')
-- 'AȘ'  # WHAT??

select replace(N'ȘAȘ', N'Ș', N'-')
-- '-AȘ' # WHAT??
```

I managed to reproduce this behavior on both SQL Sever 2008 R2 and SQL Server 2012.

Is there an explanation for these seemingly weird results? Or could it be just a bug?

My default database collation is `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a collation problem.

At first look, I had to reproduce, because it was unbelivable, but your query had the same problem for me.

If you try with a proper collation it works:

```
select replace(N'AȘ' COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN, N'Ș', N'-')
```